# Gradle searching for a dependency that's not needed, thus failing

Tags: java, gradle

I have a multi-module project which uses Gradle. The two that are related to the issue at hand are `manray-gradle-plugin` which is a Gradle plugin project, providing a single code-generating task, and `manray-core` which is a plain Java library project which requires the aforementioned plugin to generate some code.

Now, for some reason, I can't compile the plugin project anymore. It gives the following error:

```
Could not find manray:manray-core:1.0
  Searched in the following locations:
  <Long list of locations here>
Required by:
  project : > manray:manray-gradle-plugin:1.0
```

...which is weird because the plugin project doesn't reference the core project at all.

The plugin project's build.gradle is like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'maven'

dependencies {
    compile gradleApi()
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.squareup:javapoet:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.github.javaparser:javaparser-core:2.5.1'
    compile 'org.reflections:reflections:0.9.10'
    compile 'io.github.lukehutch:fast-classpath-scanner:2.0.3'
}

sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
targetCompatibility = "1.7"
```

And the core project's build.gradle is like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: "manray-gradle-plugin"

sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
targetCompatibility = "1.8"

ext {
    manrayOutputDir = file("$buildDir/generated-sources/manray/")
}

[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ["src/"]

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

processComponents {
    generatedSourcesDirectory = manrayOutputDir
    classpath = sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
}
compileJava.dependsOn processComponents
```

Finally, the whole project's build.gradle is like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'manray:manray-gradle-plugin:+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "Manray"
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}
```

Also, the settings.gradle looks like this:

```
include ':manray-gradle-plugin', ':manray-core'
```

What could cause the build to fail? I've tried cleaning the project, invalidating the gradle caches... Nothing seems to work here.

Comment: Run `gradle dependencies` and verify if there's no core dependency defined anywhere. If it's not maybe cleaning cache will help?